# How to parse string with {{}}

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string

```
var str = "{{a}} {{b}} aaa";
```

I want to split the string with `{{}}`. So, my expected result is

```
array = ["a", "b"]
```

**Update**:

As another case, given

```
var str1 = "{{a {{b}}}}",
    str2 = "{{{a}}}";
```

The result should be

```
var arr1 = ["b"],
    arr2 = ["a"];
```

Comment: So where'd the spaces and the `aaa` go?

Comment: How do you want to handle cases like `'{{a {{b}}}}'` and `'{{{a}}}'`?

Comment: @ceejayoz - They aren't enclosed in `{{}}`.

Comment: in @ChrisHunt case, the my result will be `["a {{b}}", "{a}"]`

Comment: @TedHopp OP says they want to split the string. It does appear they don't want to split it, but instead tease out certain portions of it, ala template tags or something. I'm asking for clarification.

Comment: Also, how do you want to handle something like `"{{ab}c}}"`?

Comment: You can use `/{{([^}]*?)}}/g` Here's [**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/zgqwqgea/)

Comment: `str.replace(/({{)([^{])(}})/g,"$2")`

Comment: @Tushar, this is not a duplicate, the answer on the other post does not work in the cases specified above.

Comment: If `'{{a {{b}}}}` is supposed to yield `'a {{b}}'`, you aren't going to do that with a regex, at least if you want to handle arbitrarily deep nesting of `{{}}` pairs. That's more than a finite state automaton can handle. See [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133601/can-regular-expressions-be-used-to-match-nested-patterns), for example.

Comment: @VuLeAnh I've reopened the question. Please [edit] the question to add those details.

Comment: @VuLeAnh what criteria do you have in mind that makes `'{{{a}}}'` go to `['{a}']` but `'{{a}} {{b}}'` go to `['a', 'b']`? There's some ambiguity there.

Comment: @ChrisHunt I just want to get string between '{{' and '}}'

Comment: The problem is that `'a}} {{b'` is between `{{` and `}}` in my second example but that's not what you want to happen.

Comment: @VuLeAnh : `'{{a}} {{b}}'` ==> `'a}} {{b`

Comment: @ChrisHunt Thanks for clear my mistake. So, the result in your case should be `['b']` and `['a']`

Comment: Another clarification request. How do you want to handle something like `"{a {{b}}}"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) them all, then extract the contents.

```js
var units = [
    "{{a}} {{b}} aaa",
    "{{a {{b}}}}",
    "{{{a}}};"
];
units.forEach(function(str) {
    var matched = str.match(/{{([^}]*[^{]*)}}/g).map(function(s) {
        return s.substring(2, s.length - 2)
    });
    console.log(str, '=');
    console.log(matched);
});
```

Comment: @Tushar Yep. Done!

Comment: Cool. Here's [Demo on RegEx101](https://www.regex101.com/r/GdRgVN/3). Please add explanation of the regex as well.

Comment: check with `"{{a {{b}} {{c}}}}"`

Comment: @PranavCBalan Blarg. Depending on what it should output, maybe not perfect.

Comment: @Tushar : I think he needs `a {{b}} {{c}}` , regex is not a correct solution for this....

Comment: Sorry all for my confusing question because I do not imagine all cases.

Comment: Sorry all for my confusing question. I did not imagine all cases
@AlexanderO'Mara Could you please update your answer as before

Comment: @VuLeAnh How so? I'm not sure regex can solve these more-complicated balancing issues.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara I think my expectation it is more complicated. I accepted your before answer `var matched = str.match(/{{[^}]}}/g).map(function(s) {
  return s.substring(2, s.length - 2)
});`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned there might not be a best way to cover every scenario, but split could be used like:

```
var str1 = "{{a}} {{b}} aaa", str2 = "{{a {{b}}}}", str3 = "{{{a}}};"

var splits = str1.split(/[^{][^.][^}]|[{}]/).filter(Boolean);
console.log(splits);
```

Results:

```
Array [ "a", "b" ]
Array [ "b" ]
Array [ "a" ]
```

Examples:

https://jsfiddle.net/gsL46bg7